# Should I use MongoDB or Neo4j

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I want to migrate a multi-user feed reader from MySQL to a NoSQL database but I cannot decide whether MongoDB or Neo4j is better for the application.

This is the current database schema:
[image: Current database schema]

The application has the following use cases:

Users:

- add/remove/activate user

Subscriptions:

- add a subscription (title of the subscription should be editable by the user)
- remove subscription for one user (and the feed when no other user subscribes it)
- list all subcriptions of an user (count of unread entries should be displayed)

Entries:

- list all entries of the user (must be filterable by the feed, bookmark flag and read flag)
- get a single entry (would be automatically marked as read)

Bookmarks:

- bookmark an entry
- remove bookmark

Which database would you propose? My instinct says MongoDB because I have no "highly interconnected" data but I have problems with migrating the user_entries table. Maybe you have some tips how you to model that relationship with MongoDB?

Update: Neo4j has the advantage that I am able to embed it into my Java application. I'm using Spring Data Neo4j/MongoDB and QueryDSL as data access layer. As far as I understand, Spring Data MongoDB would automatically map all associations (@DbRef) into one document and that could result in a very huge overhead with a growing number of entries. On the other hand I could use manual references as stated here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/

Comment: You'll need to model it to see if it fits your technical requirements. There's a lot of good material for learning about modeling with MongoDb on MongoDb's web site. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/ It's important to realize that you should be concerned with the queries that you'll need to run early on in your design as it greatly impacts MongoDb models.

Comment: As your relational model already has 2 JOIN tables and your use-cases also seem to be along managing those relationships and entries collected from those feeds, a graph database might do better than a document database.

Comment: You may try OrientDB. http://www.orientechnologies.com

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer:** since I'm working for Neo4j, my opinion here might be biased.

There is a well documented graph model for activity streams called 'graphity'. It's examplained [here](http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/graphity-an-efficient-graph-model-for-retrieving-the-top-k-news-feeds-for-users-in-social-networks/) (seems the link is temporarily down, use the [variant from web.archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20131103143403/http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/2012SocialComEfficientGraphModelsForRetrievingTopKNewsFeedsFromEgoNetworks.pdf)). It's also referenced in the [Neo4j manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-graphity.html).

This model looks pretty close to what you need, however some changes might be necessary. But it's definitely a great starting point.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very subjective question; it's hard to give good solid advice here without knowing what the query patterns for the application will be.  Some of the simpler use cases you've given here like just adding a new object or two, it probably won't make much difference which one you choose.

Based on the limited information you've given us, it seems like either would do just fine -- but if I had more information about your situation I might feel differently.

I'll offer the very weak suggestion of mongo, for this reason -- one of the real key things that neo4j does really well is path-associative queries (think "friend of a friend" style queries).  That's one area where it kind of blows away the competition, and I don't see a compelling need for that or other special sauce that neo4j offers.   This is not to say that neo4j can't do it (it totally can) just that your application doesn't look  like it would be using neo4j in its particular area of strength over the alternatives.